# Python Selenium - 2 buttons with same name

Tags: python, selenium, button, element

I am trying to click on a button but I am not able to do it because there are 2 buttons with similar name class, and I can't click the button I want.

```
    Button 1: 
<button class="dropdown-trigger"> 
   <i class="icon2-arrow-down">
      ::before

    Button 2:
<button class="dropdown-trigger is visible-desktop"> 
   <i class="icon2-arrow-down arrow-icon">
      ::before
```

I want to click only in button 1, can you help me?

Comment: Have you looked at [locating by XPath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)?

Comment: Instead of providing handcrafted HTML update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using *Chrome browser*, (I don't know about other browser's developer's tool, but there must be something similar...) it's easy to pick up unique element.

1. Press 'F12' key to open Chrome developer's tool. (The page might be refreshed.)
2. Right click the button you want to focus on.
3. Click 'Inspect'.
4. In the developer's tool on the left side of your browser, something will be changed, and there should be a grey box across the HTML source code. (If you move your mouse on it, the button you've inspected should be highlighted)
5. Right click the grey-colored line then click 'Copy - Copy Selector'. (In your flavor, you can copy other features to find that element)
6. You can now use the copied selector (or any feature) to find exactly one element you've designated.

If you have any question, please leave comment on this post. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't undestand why I need that. I am using python (selenium) and I need to click a button, I already tried

```
driver.find_element_by_link_claas_name("dropdown-trigger").click()

```
And I tried other things but I couldn't do it

Comment: @AndréAlmeida If you copy the CSS selector using Chrome developer's tool, the selector becomes very specific: only the element you've right-clicked will be selected using that. try using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(...)`.

Comment: I get an error saying: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: @AndréAlmeida That is because the element you want to pick is not on the running webdriver browser. Try to navigate your webdriver to the page where the button you're seeking exists(using `driver.get(...)` function). Then try following the direction I posted!

Comment: @AndréAlmeida You must be undergoing hard time... Do you get `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page documen` error when executing `find_element_by_css_selector` function? Well, try to reload the page, then right click the button to copy css selector of it, then execute the function again. The error occurs because the page or certain HTML element is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes I get that! I already reloaded the page but still the same error... Let me explain to you the process: In my web page, I am searching for some numbers in a "search box", after that, I get just one option and this option is what I  want to click.. So, if I reload the page, I get all options again in my webpage, and not the one I searched in "search box".

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".dropdown-trigger.visible-desktop").click()
```

Or you may try getting the element of the two it finds that is displayed...

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dropdown-trigger')
button = next(filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed() == True, buttons))
button.click()
```

Comment: In the first code you sent I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".dropdown-trigger.visible-desktop"}

In the second one it clicks the wrong button...